# How can I make highlighted points stay after regraphing using flot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection, flot, highlight

Currently, I have a plot that supports "lockable" points. I register a plotclick event, highlight the point, and display a tooltip that I give the id of `"lockedPoint" + item.dataindex`. I also have a zoom feature that uses jquery.flot.selection.js. By using this, I modify my x and y axis maximums and minimums, and I replot my data (essentially throwing away the old data). I am trying to preserve the "locked points" when zooming.

One solution I have thought of is when gathering my data, I can specifically push the point into the correct place in the series that it needs to be if it is within range of the zoom and then highlight the point. However, this does not seem to be working correctly.

I store the data about "locked points" in an associative array initialized like this.

```
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++){
   lockedPoints["Series " + i] = [];
}
```

Then I allow a maximum of three items to be pushed onto each array (max of three lockable points per series). I would replace the point in the array with the new highlighted point (I believe the only thing that would change would be the dataindex). Is it possible that I could make points survive zooming by pushing them into the data series when gathering data?

```
function gatherData(kElement, a0Element){
//PRE:   kElement is the id of the element containing the rate constant, and a0Element is the id of the element
//          containing the molarity
//POST:  FCTVAL is a data series in the format of {data: data, lines: {show: true}, color: "color", label: "label"}
   var xData = [];                                       //x-coordinates
   var yData = [];                                       //y-coordinates
   var data = [];                                        //array of coordinate pairs
   var startingPoint;                                    //least x-value to graph
   var finishingPoint;                                   //greatest x-value to graph
   var range;                                            //range of x-values
   var interval;                                         //value to evenly space x-values for calculations
   var current;                                          //current value of x-coordinate for which we are 
                                                         //    calculating a y-value
   var labelParent;                                      //parent node of x-axis labels
   var k;                                                //rate constant value
   var molarValue;                                       //molarity value
   var result;                                           //result of the rate equation

   numXPoints = 1001;

   if (document.getElementById("logCheck").value == "On"){      //graph logarithmically
      logarithmic = true;
   }
   else{                                                          //graph decay
      logarithmic = false;
   }

   if (document.getElementById("blackWhite").value == "On"){
      blackWhite = true;
   }
   else{
      blackWhite = false;
   }

   k = document.getElementById(kElement).value;
   molarValue = document.getElementById(a0Element).value;

   startingPoint = minX;                                             //we will say time starts at 0 always for this plot
   finishingPoint = maxX;

   range = finishingPoint - startingPoint;                        //calculated range for determining points to plot
   interval = range / numXPoints;                                 //we will graph numXPoints points
   current = startingPoint;                           

   result = molarValue * Math.pow(Math.E, (-k * current));
   if (logarithmic){                                              //for logarithmic calculations
      result = Math.log(result);
   }
   if (result > maxValue){                                        //store largest y-value                         
      maxValue = result;
   }

   for (var i = 0; i < numXPoints; i++){                        //store x-values and calculated y-values
                                                                  //    and find max y-value
      xData[i] = current;
      yData[i] = result;
      current += interval;
      result = molarValue * Math.pow(Math.E, (-k * current));

      if (logarithmic){                                           //for logarithmic calculations
         result = Math.log(result);
      }

      if (yData[i] > maxValue){                                   //store largest y-value
         maxValue = yData[i];
      }
      if (yData[i] < minValue && minValue > -400){                //store smallest y-value
         minValue = yData[i];
      }
   }

   for (var i = 0; i < numXPoints; i++){                        //combine coordinates into one series
      data[i] = [xData[i], yData[i]];
   }

   //modified jquery.flot.js to support dashed line hover.
   //values modified were pointRadius and radius in the drawPointHighlight method.
   if (blackWhite == true){
      switch(kElement){
         case "kValue1":
         return {points:{show: true, radius: 0}, data: data, lines:{show: true}, color: "black", label: "Series 1", shadowSize: 0};
         break;
      case "kValue2":
         return {points:{show: true, radius: 0}, data: data, dashes:{show: true, dashLength: 2}, color: "black", label: "Series 2", shadowSize: 0};
         break;
      case "kValue3":
         return {points:{show: true, radius: 0}, data: data, dashes:{show: true, dashLength: 10}, color: "black", label: "Series 3", shadowSize: 0};
         break;
      case "kValue4":
         return {points:{show: true, radius: 0}, data: data, dashes:{show: true, dashLength: 20}, color: "black", label: "Series 4", shadowSize: 0};
         break;
      }
   }
   else{
      switch (kElement){                                             //return proper object to match flot graph description
         case "kValue1":
            return {points:{show: false, radius: 0}, data: data, lines:{show: true}, color: "red", label: "Series 1"};
            break;
         case "kValue2":
            return {points:{show: false, radius: 0}, data: data, lines:{show: true}, color: "blue", label: "Series 2"};
            break;
         case "kValue3":
            return {points:{show: false, radius: 0}, data: data, lines:{show: true}, color: "green", label: "Series 3"};
            break;
         case "kValue4":
            return {points:{show: false, radius: 0}, data: data, lines:{show: true}, color: "gold", label: "Series 4"};
            break;
      }
   }
}
```

I can find a way to deal with the tooltip removal, but highlighting the same point is the most trivial part.

[image]

Comment: How are you redrawing your plot?  Don't re-init, so this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24785926/16363.  I believe your highlights will stay if you re-draw, instead of re-init.

Comment: See this demo, highlight a few points and then click the button: http://jsfiddle.net/NVxU6/

Comment: The problem with only redrawing is that the amount of visible points is constantly reduced when zooming, and I would like to have the graph always be hoverable and clickable. To do that, I would have to re-init (I believe).

Comment: I don't understand *the amount of visible points is constantly reduced when zooming*, can you elaborate?

Comment: Essentially, a series is a finite number of coordinate sets. If I only adjust the view of the data, but I don't adjust the data to calculate new points after zooming (making it appear that I have graphed an infinite amount of points), I will see only a few of the original points, making the hover feature "spotty".  Does that clarify what I was trying to say?

Comment: I understand now.  You can still manipulate the data before a redraw.  See this update to my example: http://jsfiddle.net/NVxU6/1/.  After the "zoom" I'm using `setData` to pad the points.

Comment: Mark you've been a lot of help! I would like to ask you about the tooltip issue as well. I am having trouble identifying which points are still highlighted. I store the plotclick items in the `lockedPoints` array, but I cannot figure out how to retrieve the updated information. Is there a way to get all highlighted points of a plot? Perhaps a `getHighlights()` method? Is there a way I can direct message you about this because it's not entirely related to this post?

Comment: It would be better if you just opened a new question.  That way others can benefit from it and it's preserved for "posterity".  Also, I'm going to answer this question with a summary of our conversation here, that way we can close it.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind taking a look, I'd greatly appreciate your help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24879551/how-can-i-reposition-tooltips-used-to-display-information-about-highlighted-poin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a combination of `setupGrid` and `draw`, the highlights will persist between redraws and you won't need to manually reapply (like you would if you re-init).

Also, to manipulate the data between re-draws (say on the zoom selection), use a combination of `getData` and `setData`:

```
$("#flot_chart").bind("plotselected", function (event, ranges) {
    var fr = ranges.xaxis.from;
    var to = ranges.xaxis.to;
    $.each(plot.getXAxes(), function(_, axis) {
        var opts = axis.options;
        opts.min = fr;
        opts.max = to
    });
    //pad data points, so the hover effect doesn't look spotty
    var series = plot.getData(); // get series
    series[0].data = []; // clear it out
    for (var i = fr; i < to; i+=(to-fr)/100){
        series[0].data.push([i,Math.sin(i)]); // push in data with a suitable increment to i
    }
    plot.setData(series); // set the new data  
    plot.setupGrid(); // redo the grid
    plot.draw(); // redraw the plot
    plot.clearSelection();
});
```

Here's a fiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/NVxU6/1/).